# C# parsing information from a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, parsing, text

I am trying to parse some data from a folder that contains text files. I have gotten to the point where I have obtained the desired data in a string array. I would like to parse the data as follows [int, int, string, double] currently, it looks like [string, string, string, string].

Now I know I cannot save the data into the same array but I was hoping to parse the integers and use them for coordinates, then parse the string and use it as a name, and finally parse the double as a theta.

Right now this is what I have

```
foreach (var str in data) 
{
   // so this will look into every string[] that is within d,ata. However I am running a 
   //blank on how to parse the data as desired.
}
```

If anyone has suggestions that would be great, most of my google searches have led to more confusion.

EDIT:

so the data would be stored in a text file and look something like this

```
12 45 acute .67
32 78 hypotenuse .12
.
.
.
and so on.
```

I used a Tuples list to achieve this but I am getting a weird result where all of my ints are stay the same as the first line of ints

so instead of the list looking like

```
(12 45 acute .67)
(32 78 hypotenuse .12)
.
.
.
and so on
```

it looks like

```
(12 45 acute .67)
(12 45 hypotenuse .12)
.
.
.
and so on
```

below is my current code

so I initialized a Tuple and another list to hold the integers

then in my for loop

```
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(file))
    {
         var values = line.Split(" ");
         for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         {
               //this is the integer list
               positions.Add(int.Parse(values[i]));
         }
         var category = values[3];
         var certainty = Double.Parse(values[4]);
         // now we add all this data to the Tuple list
         results.Add(new(positions[0], positions[1],
                     category, certainty));
     }
```

So as I wrote out that code, I realized that I am hard coding my results to display only the first pair of x,y coordinates instead. Correct me if I am wrong. So the change should look something like

```
results.Add(new(positions.Item1, positions.Item2,
                cateogry, certainty));
```

Comment: So `data` contains one line of data, split on space or whatever, and contains something like `{ "42", "21", "hello", "0.5" }`? Then go like `if (!int.TryParse(data[0], out var firstInt)) { throw }` and so on and use `firstInt` and so on, don't use a foreach.

Comment: `int.TryParse()`?  `double.TryParse()`?  It's not really clear to me where you're stuck.  Parsing strings into integers/doubles is something easily found with your favorite search engine.  Perhaps you could expand this to a [mcve] which demonstrates hard-coded input data and your attempt to parse the values you need, indicating what specifically isn't working as expected?

Comment: Just curious, what kind of data do you try to parse? Is it CSV, XML, json, or something completely different?

Comment: Looks like csv to me, I suggest to use a csv library, as they do the heavy work for you and handle things like escaping. Try [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class.

```
class Coordinate {
  int X;
  int Y;
  string Name;
  double Theta;
}
```

Later, create a List from this dummy class.

```
List<Coordinate> myList = new List<Coordinate>();
```

As I understand that this data is ordered. Iterate your incoming data ,create an object and fill the list like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
   Coordinate myCoord = new Coordinate();
   var parsingResult;
   int modResult = i%4;
   switch(modResult) {
    case 0:  int.Parse(data[i], parsingResult); myCoord.X = parsingResult;  break; // Integer
    case 1:  int.Parse(data[i], parsingResult); myCoord.Y = parsingResult; break; // Integer
    case 2:  myCoord.Name = data[i]; break; // String
    case 3:  double.Parse(data[i], parsingResult); myCoord.Theta = parsingResult; break; // Double
   }
   myList.Add(myCoord);
}
```

Comment: I like this idea as well, But I went with using Tuples instead. It seems similar though?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't prefer Tuples. The reason is that I prefer to work with class which only contains primitive types. I believe that code will clean and fit OOP rules in better way in that case. However, I do not know your all project and if you are okay using Tuple and fix your issue, then no problem, go with it.

Comment: I marked it as the answer, but I did go ahead with Tuples. However if it seems to be an issue in the future I will reference your code.